# What are examples of functions F,G and sets A,B such that $F : A \to B$, $G : B \to A$, $(G \circ F)= I_A$, and $G \neq F^{-1}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Suppose F and G are functions such that $F : A \to B$, $G : B \to A$,  $(G \circ F)= I_A$, and $G \neq F^{-1}$ where A and B are sets.

I need to find an example of functions $F$ and $G$ and sets $A$ and $B$ such that the above is true.

I'm thinking the answer might be:

$F(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $G(x) = x^2$

$F(G(x)) = \sqrt{x^2} = |x|$ but $G(F(x))=G(\sqrt{x})= (\sqrt{x})^2 = x$

I have satisfied $(G \circ F)= I_A$ because $G(F(x))= x$.

I have satisfied $G \neq F^{-1}$ because $F(G(x)) \neq G(F(x)$ (since $|x| \neq x)$

My only problem is F goes from $(0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ whereas G goes from $(-\infty, \infty) \to (0,\infty)$.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: There are examples in which $A$ has just one element and $B$ has two.  In fact, for such $A$ and $B$, **any** functions $F:A\to B$ and $G:B\to A$ provide an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be nonnegative integers, $B$ be all integers.

$$
F: A -> B : n \mapsto n \\
G: B -> A : n \mapsto |n|
$$
Since G is not 1-1, it cannot be the inverse of $F$. (Indeed, because $F$ is not surjective (on "onto"), $F$ cannot have an inverse.